# How to add columns and delete columns in a Json file then save it into csv

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, multiple-columns

I have tried to use dataframe to add columns and values into the json file, but it seems like after I tried to delete some columns it return to the original data file. I also faced a problem of not able to save it into a csv file. So was wondering maybe I cannnot use dataframe for this?

It is like a list and divided into different columns (around 30 rows in total), however some I would like to delete like the route and urls, while adding three columns with length, maxcal, mincal (all the values in these 3 columns are found in the route columns)

I had done this so far and got stucked:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = pd.read_json('fitness.json') # fitness.json is the filename of the json file

fitness2 = pd.DataFrame (fitness2)
fitness2

data.join(fitness2, lsuffix="_left") # to join the three columns into the data table
```

I am not sure how can I delete the columns of route, 'MapURL', 'MapURL_tc', 'MapURL_sc' then finally save as a csv like the output shown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can drop columns and then concat the two dataframes:

```py
data.drop(['MapURL', 'MapURL_tc', 'MapURL_sc'], inplace=True, axis=1)

pd.concat([data,fitness2], axis=1) # to join the three columns into the data table
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes I did that but then if I add columns using data.join(fitness2, lsuffix="_left"), it will print out my original txt file. And I am not sure how to save the new edited ones in csv, seems like couldnt save to csv when in dataframe

Comment: can you please post fitness.json as text on the post so that I can test the code?

Comment: sure, have posted.

Comment: see if it works now